# Show input field above keyboard mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, unity-ui

Common ux case on mobile is to have the view magically scrolling when keyboard shows up so that input field remains visible above keyboard

Mobile sdks like Xamarin, ios or android would provide that functionality natively.

Would there be such command in Unity?

I could consider a default position and make the canvas/scroll view move accordingly but maybe there is already something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up finding this one

https://forum.unity.com/threads/move-ui-above-touchkeyboard-for-mobile.353493/

I have not tried the code but this is as close to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this behavior is not *native* in Unity at all.

You can use [`TouchScreenKeyboard.visible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-visible.html) to detect if the keyboard is on screen and modify your UX as necessary yourself, though.

The docs on the `TouchScreenKeyboard` class says:

> `TouchScreenKeyboard.visible` and `TouchScreenKeyboard.area` should be used to determine if the keyboard is being shown (activated) and what portion of the screen is using.

Comment: As i thought. I was just trying my luck. I guess i'll figure out smg. Thanks.

Comment: So after a bit of research, first the TouchScreenKeyboard.area returns rect 0 on Android which is not going to make things easier...So as I have no way to know the area occupied by the keyboard, this makes it quite impossible.

Comment: @Everts I haven't messed with it before myself. I've not made an app where it's come up.

Comment: No worries, i was just updating on my attempt to find a solutio using your tips. And first result on Android is not so promissing.

Comment: @Everts Mess around with it, you'll either find another question or a better answer. :)